# How to enter varible type Fragment in method?

Tags: android, fragment

I use a method in the library, but I could not put the right parameter.

```
public class CutFragment extends Fragment {
btnPickAudioPath1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {


        new MaterialFilePicker()
                .withFragment(CutFragment.this) // getting error here
                .withRequestCode(1000)
                .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.mp3$")) // Filtering files and directories by file name using regexp
                .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
                .start();

      }
    });
}
```

**This is method in library**

```
/**
 * Specifies fragment, which will be used to
 * start file picker
 */
public MaterialFilePicker withFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (mSupportFragment != null || mActivity != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You must pass either Activity, Fragment or SupportFragment");
    }

    mFragment = fragment;
    return this;
}
```

Normally if we specifies activity we will use MainActivity.this, so if specify fragment how we get the Fragment? Thanks.

This is the error messages.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.auroralife, PID: 1745
    java.lang.RuntimeException: You must pass Activity/Fragment by calling withActivity/withFragment/withSupportFragment method
        at com.nbsp.materialfilepicker.MaterialFilePicker.start(MaterialFilePicker.java:217)
        at com.example.auroralife.Fragment.CutFragment$2.onClick(CutFragment.java:123)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

[If I use getActivity()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVpkW.png)

Comment: have you tried simply passing `this` please also post the log error you are getting

Comment: Make sure your fragment has the same import as library method expects, because Fragment class can have one of two different imports: 1. import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 2. import android.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
new MaterialFilePicker()
        .withSupportFragment(this) //try this
        .withRequestCode(FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
        .withHiddenFiles(true)
        .start();
```

And to get response you can call `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String path = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);

        if (path != null) {
            Log.d("Path (fragment): ", path);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Picked file in fragment: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help! :)

Comment: "withSupportFragment(this)" - if he use this code then he'll get an error because "this" will point at View.OnClickListener class, so you need to replace "this" to "CutFragment.this"

Answer (score 0):

you can call this MaterialFilePacker function on your activity class

In Activity class define fragment globally :

```
CutFragment cutFragment;
```

and define a function which is call your method

```
private void a(){
           new MaterialFilePicker() // remove fragment row
                .withRequestCode(REQUEST_CODE)
                .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.mp3$")) // Filtering files and directories by file name using regexp
                .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
                .start();
}
```

on your activity result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           cutFragment.b()
        }
}
```

In your fragment define a function for your todo

```
public void b(){
 //todo
}
```